# SSRS Create Excel Icon on Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Does anyone know of a way to add an Excel icon somewhere more visible for the user to do an export without having to click on "Actions".  Not sure if any of that is customizable?

Additionally, is there a way to create a drill-through report that renders in Excel.  I was trying to figure out the RS:format stuff, but not sure how to use this.

I'm trying to make the report as user friendly as possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There certainly is, you can do an export using a URL as detailed in this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154040.aspx.

All you need to do is set that as the action of an image you place on the report, and you have an export icon.  The general format is:

```
http://myrshost/ReportServer?/myreport&rs:Format=Excel
```

The main item to note is that `myrshost/ReportServer` is not going to be the same address as you use when browsing through reports.  Instead, it's probably going to be `SERVERNAME/ReportServer_INSTANCENAME`, filling in the name of your server and database instance respectively.

**Edit:** A more concrete example of what this would look like:

```
http://sqlhost/ReportServer_Report2016?/Rentals/Balance%20Overview&rs:Format=Excel
```

Comment: Thanks.  In my organization, I don't have access to add or update anything to the report server.  It takes a monthly release for IT to get anything into the report server.  Because of this, it will take me a while to test this out...even to a UAT report server.

Comment: Well, the good thing about the link portion is that you should be able to test it independently.  Even if you're literally typing the text into your browser's address bar and use the path from another report.